# C++ << overloading with ostream for correct formatting

Tags: c++, overloading, ostream

I've started to play with coding my own linklist, It works fine for printing numbers but i use Templates in order to determine typename for use with objects. As such i have no issues entering data except printing objects. I get the following error with these classes but Visual studio 2010 doesn't give a line number. All i'm trying to do is allow different types of objects to be outputted from the linklist with the correct formatting.

```
error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &
__cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,
class Customer &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVCustomer@@@Z)
already defined in Customer.obj
```

Gui Class

```
//Templates
#include "LinkList.h"
#include "Node.h"

//Classes
#include "Gui.h"
#include "Customer.h"

//Libaries
#include <iostream>

//Namespaces
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Customer c1("TempFirst", "TempLast");
    LinkList<Customer> customerList;
    customerList.insert(c1);

    //Print Linklist
    customerList.print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Customer Class

```
//Def
#pragma once

//Included Libaries
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Customer
{
private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
public:
    Customer();
    Customer(std::string sFirstName, std::string sLastName);
    ~Customer(void);

    //Get Methods
    std::string getFirstName();
    std::string getLastName();

    //Set Methods
    void setFirstName(std::string sFirstname);
    void setLastName(std::string sLastname);

    //Print
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, Customer& customer)
{
    output << "First Name: " << customer.getFirstName() << " "
        << "Last Name: " << customer.getLastName() << std::endl;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Have you templatized the << function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful about putting function definitions in the header file. You either need to inline the definition or, better yet, put it in a `.cpp` file instead. In `Customer.h` just put a function prototype:

```
// Customer.h
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, Customer& customer);
```

And put the full definition in `Customer.cpp`:

```
// Customer.cpp
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, Customer& customer)
{
    output << "First Name: " << customer.getFirstName() << " "
           << "Last Name: "  << customer.getLastName()  << std::endl;
    return output;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want the definition in the header file then add the `inline` keyword. Inline definitions have to go in header files, and by their nature they don't have external linkage and won't trigger duplicate definition errors.

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& output, Customer& customer)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great catch i didn't realize i did that coming from a Java background and i see how i made this mistake. Thank you, you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your not getting a line number, because the error isn't detected until
link time, and the linker doesn't see any source code.  The problem is
that you've put the function definition in the header; this is only
legal if the function is a function template or has been declared
`inline`.  The usual procedure is to put just a declaration in the
header, and put the definition in the same source file as the class
member function definitions.